# Stuck at fetching a new question after a timeout (using Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I am building a Flutter Quiz app where the user gets a specific duration of time to answer the question. If the user fails to answer within the given time frame, the next question is retrieved.

The `starttimer` method acts as a counter and stops at 1.

```
void starttimer() {
    _counter = 10;

    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }

    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        setState(() {
            if (_counter > 0) {
                print(_counter);
                _counter--;
            } else {
                _timer.cancel();
            }

            if (_counter == 1) {
               // TODO: nextQuestion();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The questions are in a list and a index is used to obtain a specific question within the Text widget ex: `Text(questionlist[i])`.

The `nextQuestion()` needs to increment the index by 1.

How can I achieve this? Or is there any other way to retrieve the next question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic:

```dart
void startTimer() {
  _counter = 10;
  _timer?.cancel();
  
  _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    setState(() {
      if (_counter == 0) {
        nextQuestion();
        timer.cancel();
      }
      _counter--;
    });
  });
}
```